# What is the reason of undesired peak current in PFC non-isolated boost converter?

Tags: current, boost, converter, power-factor-correction

I have attached inductor current waveform of PFC boost converter. After the particular current level, an undesired peak is coming. I have done some study and thinking it might be because of inductor saturation but not sure.

[image: PFC boost converter current waveform]
[image: PFC boost converter current waveform 2]

Comment: In a PFC the inductor current should (usually) follow a rectified sine (which is the reference derived from the like voltage.) However, if the line voltage itself is distorted the inductor current would try to follow that as well. So I would check the line voltage reference right at the IC. I see no indication that the inductor is close to saturation in the expanded waveforms, though I would not expect to see so much rounding of the current. I think that's due to measurement effects though.

Comment: I think you might be right about the inductor saturating.  What does the spec say?

Comment: Sir, line voltage is sinusoidal. Measurement is also good. during light load condition current nature is good but when I am applying a moderate load, current nature is  distorted.

Comment: Sir, specs of what?

Comment: There are multiple causes possible. 1) Noisy waveshaping input (AC voltage sensing used for AC current waveform synthesis) 2) Unstable current loop. I don't see this as boost inductor saturation as the rising edges of the ramps look similar between the two waveforms posted. Unless you post a schematic and provide more details (input voltage, output voltage, load applied) you will only receive speculative answers.

Answer (score 1):

I observed same behaviour in interleaved PFC controlled by MCU. At higher load same peaks at coils currents affect the line current. Higher Proportional value of current loop controller help slightly together with some feedforward shape which help current controllers performance. Some people have similar problem with TI pfc IC, but there was the problem with some clamping of internal structure - the solution was to decrease shunt value.

[image: oscilloscope trace]

<sub>(Image source: [TI E2E forum topic: UCC28180: UCC28180 PFC : distorsion of the PFC coil current](http://e2e.ti.com/support/power-management/f/196/t/603478) [sic])</sub>

But in my case the shunt voltage after amplification with OPAMP is far from ADC max 3.3V. My current scale is 8Amps and issue is at 3-4Amp

Answer (score 1):

The reason of spikes is that voltage PI controller is set "too high" to compensate voltage ripple on DC bus cap and its distort the reference current shape - output of controller change its value within half AC mains period.

The output of voltage controller must be slow or DC value from controller output must be taken at Vin zero cross. In that way the multiply DC value by reference voltage will produce reference current.

The small drawback of PFC is that there is ripple on DC bus cap because of sine input current. If the user want perfect DC-bus voltage regardless input current than the output from voltage controller will go directly into current controller without multiply with reference sine(ABS)voltage. But in this case the mains current will be very strange.

Answer (score 0):

In general: A boost converter is a kind of switching regulator, where a current flowing through a coil is switched on and off. This switching action causes very abrupt current change which results in very high coil voltage (V=L*dI/dt).

Comment: Sir, But it should follow sine waveshape.

Comment: What should follow sine waveshape? Why do you expect this?

Comment: because implemented topology is the average current mode control.